# Yii redirect to user/login

Tags: php, redirect, frameworks, authentication, yii

I am noob Yii developer and I have AdminController with access rules. So this controller is enabled for only specific users, else it redirects to "example.com/site/login" but I need that it redirected to "example.com/user/login" . So can you tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can change the `loginUrl` property of the user component, so make the following change in your main.php config file:

```
array(
// ......
 'components'=>array(
    'user'=>array(
        'loginUrl'=>array('user/login'),
    ),
 ),
)
```

Read [this part](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.auth#handling-authorization-result) in the guide.

Comment: what if I had 2 loginUrl? how to deal with it

Comment: @silentbang please don't ask a question in comments. i'll try my best to answer if you ask a question, plus your question will get more views, which increases the probability of getting good specific answers. You can specify 2 urls, i think, but i'll need more detail, there must be some condition right, depending on which you'd want to use a different url in some cases, and another in other cases.

Comment: but here it seems that in main config file we can only assign one

Comment: yes, but we can do it some other way(maybe), if you ask a detailed question, as a new question, then maybe i or someone else can help you.

Answer (score 3):

In your `protected/config/main.php`, where you define parameters to all the other system components, you should define `loginUrl` for the `user` component:

```
....
'components' => array(
    'user' => array (
        'loginUrl' => array('/user/login'),
    ),
    ....
),
....
```

Docs: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CWebUser#loginUrl-detail

Comment: thank you for the answer, but your answer was not The First correct, so that is why I didn't mark it.